# Predicting a dichotomous variable

Tags: r, predictive-models, linear-model

I have a series of descriptors, some continuous, some discrete and an output variable which is dichotomous.

I have several parameters, but for the sake of simplicity let's say my data look like:

```
 Sex  |  Age  |  Genotype  | Dose 1  |  Dose  2  |  Outcome
------|-------|------------|---------|-----------|------------
  M   |  32   |    AABB    |   150   |     30    |    YES
  F   |  65   |    aaBb    |   110   |     30    |    YES
  M   |  42   |    AaBb    |   200   |     50    |    NO
...
```

I would like to make a predictive model to determine the optimal combination of `Dose 1` and `Dose 2` to have a desired outcome.

So my question is, if I have a new male subject of given genotype and age, what is the best combination of doses that will give a positive outcome with the highest probability? Or, to see things the other way around, given the other parameters, what are the odds of having a positive outcome with a given set of doses?

I thought I could use R to generate a linear model with `glm`, and then use `predict` to predict the outcome. However, I never really dealt with this type of problems before and I am a bit confused on how to use these functions and interpret their results. Also, I am not sure if this is the correct way to deal with the problem.

For instance, let's generate some random data:

```
set.seed(12345)

num.obs <- 50
sex <- sample(c("M", "F"), num.obs, replace=T)
age <- sample(20:80, num.obs, replace=T)
genotype <- sample(LETTERS[1:8], num.obs, replace=T)
dose.1 <- sample(100:200, num.obs, replace=T)
dose.2 <- sample(30:70, num.obs, replace=T)
outcome <- sample(0:1, num.obs, replace=T)

data <- data.frame(sex=sex, age=age, genotype=genotype,
              dose.1=dose.1, dose.2=dose.2, outcome=outcome)
```

Which gives 50 observation such as

```
> head(data)
  sex age genotype dose.1 dose.2 outcome
1   F  78        C    183     54       0
2   F  70        E    156     66       1
3   F  39        H    180     35       0
4   F  32        E    135     51       0
5   M  64        E    121     57       1
6   M  50        H    179     61       1
```

Now, I generate a model with

```
model <- glm(outcome ~ sex + age + genotype + dose.1 + dose.2, 
    data=data, family="binomial")
```

First question: without any *a priori* knowledge of the interactions between the descriptors, **how do I choose the correct formula**? Should I try various interactions and see which models gives the best fit e.g. looking at residual deviance or AIC? Are there functions to do this for me or should I try all of the combinations manually?

OK, let's say I found the model is good, now I use `predict`

```
new.data <- list(sex=factor("M", levels=c("M", "F")), age=35, 
                 genotype=factor("C", levels=LETTERS[1:8]), 
                 dose.1=150, dose.2=30)
outcome <- predict(model, new.data, se=T)
```

Which gives:

```
$fit
        1 
-2.774538 

$se.fit
[1] 1.492594

$residual.scale
[1] 1
```

So... what do I do with this? `?predict.glm` says `$fit` is the prediction but obviously that is not a yes/no type of prediction... what I would ideally need is something on the lines of "89% YES / 11% NO".

**How do I interpret the result of `predict` and how would I go about having the type of result I want?**

Finally, **are there functions to explore the parameter space so that I get a graph with the outcome in the dose1 vs dose2 space?**

EDIT: just to clarify: I do not have a specific reason to use a generalized linear model, it is just something that came to my mind as a possible solution. If anyone can think of other ways to solve this type of problem I would gladly welcome their suggestion!

Comment: I would first include only important variables and see if there is an interaction. See that the residuals of models are OK. Use AIC (or other tests) to see if you've improved your model by incorporating/removing the interaction(s). Once you have a valid model you can go on predicting. Make sure you use `type = "response"` in your predict to transform the predicted values from logit to odds.

Comment: @Roman Luštrik: ahhhhh `type=response`! I did not know about that one! So that number I get is the logit, now it's starting to make much more sense

Comment: You can transform predict values either by `exp(x)/(1+exp(x))` (x is fitted values), `plogis(model$fit)` or using the aforementioned `type = "response"`.

Comment: The model needs to be pre-specified, and no "insignificant" variables deleted, for P-values and confidence intervals to have any accuracy.

Comment: @Frank Harrell: surely you need to pre-specify the model, but that is the question. How to best choose `output ~ sex * age` vs `output ~ sex + age`? I do not know whether some of my descriptor are insignificant, but if some are I don't see why I should keep them.

Comment: @Nico You framed this question as a problem in regression. But really, it seems like a problem from optimal decision theory: given the data, what is the optimal dosage for a particular patient?

Comment: @pteetor: surely. I will re-specify the question better, but I just specified it as a linear regression problem because that is how I (naïvely) thought about it. However, if there are better ways to analyze this type of issue (some Bayesian modeling maybe?) I would be more than happy to hear from you guys, don't be shy to leave an answer!

Comment: @FrankHarrell, can you shortly expand the reasoning behind not deleting "insignificant" variables?

Comment: It invalidates standard errors in the model (makes them too small) and biases the remaining coefficients (think of publication bias) away from zero.

Comment: @Frank Harrell: I don't understand your reasoning. If my model predicts the outcome correctly with only two descriptor I don't see why I should add more noise adding other parameters. Otherwise following your reasoning I should include any other possible parameter in my model (how many people in the room when the measures where done, the temperature outside, the phase of the moon, whether someone was using the coffee machine next door, the position of Saturn at the time and so on and so on...).

Comment: What you said would be correct if the "only two descriptors" were entirely pre-specified.  However instead of that you are advocating the use of the data to determine which predictors should be in the model.  This is double dipping, and stepwise variable selection without shrinkage has been proven not to work.  Think about bias, multiplicity, underestimation of standard errors by pretending that the final model was pre-specified and hence ignoring a major source of uncertainty.  What I'n saying does not imply adding the kitchen sink to the model;this is where subject matter knowledge comes in.

Comment: @Frank Harrell: then why don't you give an answer? Let's say I do not drop any descriptor (still don't completely get why I should not, but I trust you on that one, as you're surely way more expert than I am). How do I choose the formula for my model? Also, note that the dataset is constantly being updated with new data, in order to improve the model.

Comment: There are at least three safe approaches as described in my text Regression Modeling Strategies or my course notes which are at http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/rms.  (1) Fit a very large model using penalized maximum likelihood estimation. (2) Use data reduction blinded to Y to reduce the number of predictors. (3) Use subject matter expertise to reduce the number of variables to what the effective sample size will support.

Comment: @Frank Harrell: thank you, I will have a good read at that.